No overload matches this call error, on the '$pull' operator
I'm new to typescript and I'm stuck with this error. What is the problem here and what should I do?

No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 4, '(filter:
Filter, update: UpdateFilter, options:
FindOneAndUpdateOptions & { includeResultMetadata: true; }):
Promise<...>', gave the following error.
Type '{ friends: { username: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'PullOperator'.
Type '{ friends: { username: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'NotAcceptedFields<Document, readonly any[]>'.
Property 'friends' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '{ username: string; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.   Overload 2 of 4, '(filter: Filter, update:
UpdateFilter, options: FindOneAndUpdateOptions & {
includeResultMetadata: false; }): Promise<...>', gave the following
error.

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import  { findUserDetails } from "@/app/helpers/FindUserId";
import client from "@/lib/db";

export async function DELETE(req: NextRequest) {
    try {
      const { username, loggedInUsername }: {username: string, loggedInUsername: string} = await req.json();
  
      if (!username || !loggedInUsername) {
        return NextResponse.json(
          { error: "Username and LoggedInUsername are required" },
          { status: 400 }
        );
      }
  
      const db = client.db();
  
      const deletedFromLoggedInUserDocument = await db.collection("users").findOneAndUpdate(
        { username: loggedInUsername },
        { $pull: { friends: { username: username } } },
        { returnDocument: "after" }
      );
  
      const deletedFromUserDocument = await db.collection("users").findOneAndUpdate(
        { username: username },
        {
          $pull: { friends: { username: loggedInUsername } }, 
          $set: { updatedAt: new Date() },
        },
        { returnDocument: "after" }
      );
  
      if (!deletedFromLoggedInUserDocument.value || !deletedFromUserDocument.value) {
        return NextResponse.json(
          { error: "Failed to update the user's friends list" },
          { status: 500 }
        );
      }
  
      return NextResponse.json({ message: "Friend deleted successfully" }, { status: 200 });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating user's friends list:", error);
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: "An internal server error occurred" },
        { status: 500 }
      );
    }
  }

